# Artefacts drawing lines in Swift Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, optimization, drawing

The below class attaches to a UIView and draws lines while moving a finger across the screen. However, when moving a finger very fast from left to right moving from top to bottom, the drawing temporarily shows sharp pointy edges on changing direction. This occurs both on the device and simulator.

What is causing this issue and how can this artefact be eliminated in the code so that only smooth rounded, not sharp edges are seen when changing direction fast?

---

[image]

---

```
class drawLine: UIView
{
var comittedSegments: Int = 0
var points = [CGPoint]()
var committedPath = UIBezierPath()

var drawPath = UIBezierPath()
var incrementalImage: UIImage?

var strokeColor:UIColor?

override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
    autoreleasepool {
        incrementalImage?.drawInRect(rect)
        strokeColor = UIColor.darkGrayColor()
        strokeColor?.setStroke()
        drawPath.lineWidth = 20
        drawPath.lineCapStyle = CGLineCap.Round
        drawPath.stroke()
    }
}

override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    let touch: AnyObject? = touches.first

    comittedSegments = 0
    committedPath.removeAllPoints()
    points.removeAll()

    points.append( touch!.locationInView(self) )
}

override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    let touch: AnyObject? = touches.first
    let point = touch!.locationInView(self)

    points.append( point )

    if points.count == 5
    {
        points[3] = CGPointMake((points[2].x + points[4].x)/2.0, (points[2].y + points[4].y)/2.0)

        committedPath.moveToPoint(points[0])
        committedPath.addCurveToPoint(points[3], controlPoint1: points[1], controlPoint2: points[2])
        comittedSegments = comittedSegments + 1

            self.setNeedsDisplay()

        points[0] = points[3]
        points[1] = points[4]

        points.removeRange(2...4)

        drawPath = committedPath
    }
    else if points.count > 1
    {

        drawPath = committedPath.copy() as! UIBezierPath

        drawPath.CGPath = committedPath.CGPath

        drawPath.moveToPoint( points[0] )
        for point in points[1..<points.count] {
            drawPath.addLineToPoint(point)
        }

        self.setNeedsDisplay()
    }
}

override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    self.drawBitmap()
    self.setNeedsDisplay()

    committedPath.removeAllPoints()
    points.removeAll()
}

override func touchesCancelled(touches: Set<UITouch>?, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    self.touchesEnded(touches!, withEvent: event)
}

func drawBitmap() {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.bounds.size, true, 0.0)
    strokeColor?.setStroke()
    if(incrementalImage == nil) {
        let rectPath:UIBezierPath = UIBezierPath(rect: self.bounds)
        UIColor.whiteColor().setFill()
        rectPath.fill()
    }

    incrementalImage?.drawAtPoint(CGPointZero)
    committedPath.stroke()
    incrementalImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
}
}
```

Comment: Possible caused by the magic `if points.count == **5**`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to setting `lineCapStyle`, set `lineJoinStyle`:

```
drawPath.lineJoinStyle = .Round
drawPath.lineCapStyle = .Round
```